# For which values the matrix $ B = \Big(\begin{matrix} A & -A\\ -A & \alpha A \end{matrix}\Big)$ results positive definite (strict)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, cholesky-decomposition

I'm trying to solve the next problem where given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ symmetric positive definite I have to find the values for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that this matrix:

$ B = \Big(\begin{matrix}
A & -A\\
-A & \alpha A
\end{matrix}\Big)$

Is positive definite. Also I notice that $B$ is symmetric, so I tried to find it's Cholesky's decomposition by block product, but I wasn't able to do so.

Comment: Can you solve the problem in the special case where $A$ is the identity matrix?

Comment: I don't think so, I guess it should be for all Symmetric positive definite matrix :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 I & I \\
 I & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 A  & -A \\
 -A & \alpha A  \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 I & I  \\
 I & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 (\alpha-1)A & 0  \\
  0& A  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: So $\alpha$ should be bigger than 1 to be positive definite?

Answer (score 3):

Another approach: this matrix can be written as the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)
$$
B = \pmatrix{1&-1\\-1 & \alpha} \otimes A.
$$
It follows that $B$ will be positive definite if and only if $\pmatrix{1&-1\\-1&\alpha}$ is positive definite.